# Netty wrapper around smack XMPP

Tags: xmpp, netty, openfire, smack

does anyone have recommendations for a netty base wrapper around smack/xmpp. I need a client talking a text based protocol over xmpp/telnet/ssh etc.

XMPP is a bit different because there is one XMPPConnection, but I need to use different xmpp peers, and the pipeline per xmpp peer needs to be changed when connecting my protocol.

Regards,
Leen

Answer (score 1):

Look at **[netty-xmpp](https://github.com/xose/netty-xmpp)** (XMPP Decoder/Encoder for Netty).